# How to remove 12.04 & install 12.10 or 13.04 when I have Windows too?

Tags: 12.04, system-installation, 13.04, windows-7, uninstall

I was a Windows user in the last year, then I heard good things about Ubuntu and finally installed 12.04 on my acer laptop.

After 5 months, I installed the KDE package on it. I was working well for a while, but after one update, my software center broke and I can't install anything on my Ubuntu.

I found some other problems too, so now I want to erase(remove) that old version and install a newer version of Ubuntu (13.04 when released! or 12.10).

Importantly, I want to keep my Windows 7. How can I replace my old Ubuntu with a new one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install it the same way you installed 12.04. And it might look daunting at first but it is very simple. I promise :-)

2 step plan:

- So burn 12.10 on to a DVD and reboot with that newly burned disc inserted into your system. Let it boot from the DVD and at some point you get asked to install.
- When you get to the installer part where it asks what to do in relation to partitioning choose to erase/replace the current Ubuntu. This will remove 12.04 and install 12.10.

Comment: boot to live Ubuntu DVD or boot my Ubuntu with DVD inserted ?(thanks for answering)

Comment: 1st one! sorry if it was unclear